# Did any of the social science experiments by the Nazis in WWII get published?

Tags: publications, academic-history

I've read that the Nazi's did a lot of cruel experimentation on Jews during WWII. I was wondering if any of these studies were published, and if they still exist. Preferably available in English.

Comment: A place to look for citations might start here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1323276/

Comment: There was news coverage of a US company using the results of Dr Mengele's experiments a couple of years ago... don't have a link to hand, but should be easy to find...

Comment: ask on history.se or historyofscience.se, much better answers to be expected there

Comment: I wouldn't call these experiments 'social science', 'medical' might be ok but 'biological experiments on humans' would fit even better. They did a lot of stuff to humans no ethics commity today would permit you to do to mice.

Answer (score 2):

Well, USA infected Guatemalans with STD's and has aided the cartels in México. The nazis werent the only ones and the controversy  about using such data is still around.

You can find some information here:

The Arolsen Archives ( Information on victims of the Holocaust and concentration camp prisoners, this can, sadly, give you some jkeywords to look for in repositories) https://collections.arolsen-archives.org/en/search/

Also the papers can still be found online. I'm not sure you will find them in english, but the library of the congress of USA and the holocaust memorial archives would be a good start if you want to search them out in english rather than german.

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but this does not look like a good answer to me. The first sentence is more like a comment; it is a digression, and possibly one that might attract strong controversy. The rest is more or less a link-only answer, except that some of the links are too generic to be useful ("search in the library of congress").

Comment: @Federico Poloni The topic is already controversial. OP asked if the papers were published and where could they be found in english and if they still exist. The link is to records that does exist and a general idea of where are files in english. The question isn't precise enough, but at least we can try to provide a general help.

Comment: Could you add a direct link to one of these papers then? Or a citation-like reference to it and a brief excerpt?